# Grouping by time difference in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT a.session_id,
         a.created_at,
         COUNT(DISTINCT a.mongo_id) AS events
  FROM table1 a
    JOIN table1 b ON a.session_id = b.session_id
  GROUP BY a.session_id,
           a.created_at
  ORDER BY a.session_id,
           a.created_at,
           COUNT(DISTINCT a.mongo_id) DESC
```

to get the following result:

```
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:31.0   22
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:32.0   10
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:34.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:38.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:41.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:42.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:43.0   2
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:44.0   2
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:45.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:46.0   2
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:47.0   2
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:50.0   2
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:51.0   2
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:52.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:53.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:55.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:56.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:57.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:00.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:01.0   2
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:03.0   3
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:06.0   1
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:07.0   2
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:09.0   4
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:10.0   30
```

I would like to group all the events occuring within a 3 second window to get the following result:

```
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:31.0   33
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:38.0   2
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:42.0   6
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:46.0   4
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:50.0   6
Session1    2018-10-09 14:04:55.0   3
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:00.0   6
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:06.0   7
Session1    2018-10-09 14:05:10.0   30
```

I would like to sum all the occurences within a 3 second period to get the resultant column, as shown above.

To try to achieve this, I used the following query:

```
WITH t AS
(
  SELECT a.session_id,
         a.created_at,
         COUNT(DISTINCT a.mongo_id) AS events
  FROM table1 a
    JOIN table1 b ON a.session_id = b.session_id
  GROUP BY a.session_id,
           a.created_at
  ORDER BY a.session_id,
           a.created_at,
           COUNT(DISTINCT a.mongo_id) DESC
)
SELECT a.session_id,
       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' +INTERVAL '1 second' *ROUND(EXTRACT('epoch' FROM a.created_at) / 3)*3 AS TIMESTAMP,
       SUM(b.events)
FROM t AS a
  JOIN t AS b ON a.session_id = b.session_id
GROUP BY a.session_id,
         ROUND(EXTRACT('epoch' FROM a.created_at) / 3)
ORDER BY a.session_id,
         TIMESTAMP
```

but this gives me numbers that are incorrect.

How do I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your query.  You are not using table `b`.

Comment: please remove postgresql tag

Comment: I'm confused:  1. Do you want to assign the start of the three seconds based on the data OR follow a fixed pattern [0-3,3-6,6-9,...].  2. Why are you joining t back to t when you are not using it? This is just asking for trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume you get the result you specify somehow.  Then you can use window functions:

```
with results as (
      <whatever>
     )
select sessionid, min(created_at), max(created_at), sum(events)
from (select r.*,
             sum( (prev_ca < created_at - interval '3 second')::int ) over (partition by sessionid order by created_at rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
      from (select r.*,
                   lag(created_at) over (partition by sessionid order by created_at) as prev_ca
            from results r
           ) r
     ) r
group by sessionid, grp;
```

What this does is determine where a group starts, by looking at the previous `created_at` and seeing if it is more than 3 seconds earlier.  If so, a group starts.

The cumulative sum of the group starts is a grouping identifier, which can be used for aggregation.

Comment: This query doesn't execute. It doesn't seem to use the table `results` and the table `r` is used twice. I'm sorry but I'm a little confused.

Comment: @Patthebug . . . It now has the `from` clause.

Comment: I now get the following error: `Invalid operation: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause;`

Comment: @Patthebug . . . That is a peculiarity of Redshift SQL.